# Is "The blue boat is an extension of my legs" a metaphor?

Tags: metaphors

In the book "The Kayak" by Debbie Spring comes the sentence, "The blue boat is an extension of my legs."

Is this phrase an example of a metaphor?

Comment: The only other alternatives are that the statement is literally true, or gibberish. Perhaps you're thinking that 'extension' 'literalises' the usage. But when looking for metaphors, take the words in their most basic senses (an extension of your legs might be an extra 3 inches if you spend 6 months in space). And you have to use the broadest sense of 'metaphor' (a not totally real comparison hopefully explaining / enlivening a truth; this includes similes, eg 'He's as fierce as a tiger').

Comment: It meanss; The blue boat feels like an extension of my legs. Writers use is to appear more realistic when in fact it makes it more imagistic.